# error: cannot find symbol while trying to run an android studio project

Tags: java, android

I am getting following error in TextboxBinding.java

### error: cannot find symbol
import android.widget.shape;
^
symbol:   class shape
location: package android.widget

### error: cannot find symbol
private final shape rootView;
^
symbol:   class shape
location: class TextboxBinding

### error: cannot find symbol
private TextboxBinding(@NonNull shape rootView) {
^
symbol:   class shape
location: class TextboxBinding

### error: cannot find symbol
public shape getRoot() {
^
symbol:   class shape
location: class TextboxBinding

### error: cannot find symbol
return new TextboxBinding((shape) rootView);
^
symbol:   class shape
location: class TextboxBinding

TextboxBinding.java

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.example.verzeo_one.databinding;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.shape;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import com.example.verzeo_one.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;

public final class TextboxBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final shape rootView;

  private TextboxBinding(@NonNull shape rootView) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public shape getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static TextboxBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static TextboxBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup parent,
      boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textbox, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static TextboxBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    if (rootView == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("rootView");
    }

    return new TextboxBinding((shape) rootView);
  }
}
```

textbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<solid  android:color = "@color/design_default_color_primary"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
<stroks android:color = "@color/white"/>


</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're getting that error because `android.widget.shape` isn't where the `Shape` class comes from.

Looking at the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape) it seems that the correct namespace is `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape`. The [`android.widget`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary) package doesn't list any class named `Shape` at all.

Comment: @ParthaBiswas I already supplied the namespace of the correct class. Why don't you try importing it? You understand how import statements work, don't you?

Comment: Mine issues was, some drawable files were moved to layout folder. So verify if all drawable files are present in drawable folder.

Comment: @iamnaran was right, this the issue for me as well and moving it to drawable folder will fix the issue.